# Device unique ID (hardware serial ID vs volume serial ID) Windows

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, deviceiocontrol

I've been messing around with the Windows API (I've been told to stay away from WMI as it's unreliable), trying to get device serial numbers for my HDs and attached USB devices. But it seems that the majority of the functionality is designed to access Volume Serial IDs and not the actual manufacturer's unique serial number of the device. These Volume Serials seem to be calculated based on the last date and time the drive was formatted.

Well, this won't do for the application I want to develop - if a device is formatted and the same info copied to that device, then when they start my application, it needs to be able to treat the internal info (identified via the serial number) as belonging to that device, which if I use the Volume Serial ID will be lost.

I looked at the code for http://www.winsim.com/diskid32/ but that seems to just return the volume serial ID. EDIT: Actually, this value is different to the volume serial, as you can see in the below output:

> ```
> Vol Name is Hellblazer
> Vol Serial is 3358611714
> Max Filelength is 255 chars
> Filesystem is NTFS
>
> 202020202020202020205a204339464a38305345
> Z9CJF08ES
> ```

The serial in the first bit of code (using GetVolumeInformation) is the decimal version of the hexidecimal value you get for the drive when typing 'vol' in the command prompt - so this is the Volume serial. The below number is what gets returned from `DeviceIoControl(hwDrive, IOCTL_STORAGE_QUERY_PROPERTY...`. It's the same ID the programmer of *diskid32* gets for my drive, yet different to the actual serial below. Perplexing.

For USB drives:
Using a `PSP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DETAIL_DATA` struct, I can get access to the GUID device enumeration, which looks like this for my USB drive:

> \?\usbstor#disk&ven_toshiba&prod_mk5059gsxp&rev_gn00#203216187542_*_*&0#{53f563
>   07-b6bf-11d0-94f2-00a0c91efb8b}

*This* part of that device information is the serial, supposedly:

> 203216187542_*_*

Additionally, I loaded up diskpart.exe (a cmd line partition program) and had a look at the drive details of my system HDD and an external USB drive and neither of them matched any of the values I'm getting above:

> TOSHIBA MK5055GSXF ATA Device Disk ID: 00005B9E
>
> TOSHIBA MK5059GSXP USB Device Disk ID: 51260D08

What could be going on here?  Where, and how can I gain access to the actual manufacture serial number of the actual device?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: One more bump. I would really like to know why there seems to be discrepancies between what the commands return and what a partitioning program managed to find.

Comment: WMI isn't unreliable, for querying stuff. It _is_ tricky to use for the event stuff, and it (back in the Windows 2000 era) had a bunch of memory leaks and other bugs in it.

Comment: `Volume Serial Number` It is generated at the time of creating and formatting the volume / partition.